# What's the Mockito verify for EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes() equivalent?

Tags: mockito, easymock

Migrating some tests from EasyMock to Mockito.

The EasyMock code is like:

```
Some mock = EasyMock.createMock(Some.class);
mock.someMethod(argMatcher);
EasyMock.expectLastCall().anyTimes();
EasyMock.replay(mock);
```

How to do the equivalent (or similar) mock-verify with Mockito?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll write a test like this:

```
Some mock = Mockito.mock(Some.class);
Mockito.when(mock.someMethod(argMatcher)).thenReturn(aReturnObject);
yourTestedObject.setSome(mock)

yourTestedObject.someTestedMethodWhichUseSomeClass();

Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).someMethod(argMatcher);
```

And for a void method:

```
Some mock = Mockito.mock(Some.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(mock).someMethod(argMatcher);
yourTestedObject.setSome(mock);

yourTestedObject.someTestMethodWhichUseSomeClass();

Mockito.verify(mock, Mockito.atLeastOnce()).someMethod(argMatcher);
```

Comment: Hi, Julien, thanks for helping me out. mock.someMethod() is a void method. Does this still apply?

Comment: Hi, for a void method, its a little bit different. You have to write your test like another way. I edit my answer to show you this.